# When is the Clifford index of a curve computed by pencils?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, line-bundles

Under which circumstances is the Clifford index of a curve computed by pencils?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost always. The *Clifford dimension* of the curve is the smallest $r$ such that the Clifford index is given by a $g^r_d$. Curves of  Clifford dimension $>1$ are rather rare. The curves of Clifford dimension 2 are exactly the smooth plane curves of degree $\geq 5$. Curves of  Clifford dimension 3 are also known; in general, there are nice conjectures of Eisenbud, Lange, Martens and Schreyer, see [here](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/CM/CM_1989__72_2/CM_1989__72_2_173_0/CM_1989__72_2_173_0.pdf).